# Unable to change state in a modal in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, next.js

I am trying to create a modal, I am using next and firebase firestore for backend, I am trying to add a functionality to an input field in a modal that takes email, on change it runs a query to find that user in my DB and if found, updates a state. I am getting the desired result until fetching user from the DB but I can't change the state for some reason.

I have created this modal using mantine:

```xml
 <Modal opened={opened} onClose={close} title="Create Your Team">
          <form>
            <Grid columns={12} justify="space-between">
              <Grid.Col span={8} className="space-y-5">
                <TextInput
                  required
                  withAsterisk
                  label="Name"
                  placeholder="Team Name"
                  {...form.getInputProps("name")}
                  value={teamName}
                  onChange={(event) => setTeamName(event.target.value)}
                />

                <TextInput
                  label="Team Members"
                  placeholder="- Enter your members' mail -"
                  rightSection={
                  <ActionIcon variant="transparent" color="gray" size="sm" radius="xl" onClick={addMember}>
                    <IconPlus size={rem(20)} strokeWidth={2} />
                  </ActionIcon>}
                  {...form.getInputProps("email")}
                  value={mail}
                  onChange={(event) => setMail(event.target.value)}
                />

                <Button
                  type="submit"
                  variant="filled"
                  color="teal"
                  // onClick={handleSubmit}
                  // disabled={submiting}
                >
                  Create Team
                </Button>
              </Grid.Col>
            </Grid>
          </form>
        </Modal>
```

and here's how I am trying to change the state, I want to have an array of users to store the list of email ids the user inputs if the email exists in the DB.

```
  const [opened, {open, close}] = useDisclosure(false);
  const [mail, setMail] = useState("");
  const [users, setUsers] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [teamName, setTeamName] = useState("");
  const form = useForm({
    validate: zodResolver(InterIntraTeamSchema),
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleMailSearch = async (event: any) => {
      if(mail.trim() !== "") {
        const user = await getUserWithMail(mail);
        console.log(user); // <---THIS IS WORKING JUST FINE.
        if(user.status === 200) {
          setUsers((prev) => {
            const updated = [...prev, user.data?.mail];
            return updated;
          }); // <--- NOT WORKING.
        }
      };
    }
    handleMailSearch(mail);
  }, [mail]);
```

I tried to check if the state is changing like this but it just logs undefined:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(users);
  }, [users]);
```